# Python randint() repeats numbers - seed is not the problem?

Tags: python, random

i do learn Python for scientific working. At the moment i try to generate a 10x10 random Matrix with binary entries: 0 and 1. I already got a solution with numpy BUT im interested of what is the error in my own solution.

The Idea is to Access every entry of my Matrix seperately and assign a value to it by calling random.randint(0, 1 ) within two while loops. In Advance i define a dummy 10x10 Matrix called "World" and reassign ist values it in the loop. The Code Looks how follows:

```
import random

World=list(10*[10*[0]]) #this is my dummy matrix

i=0
j=0

while i <= 9:
    while j <= 9:
        World[i][j]=random.randint(0, 1) #here i want to Access a specific element of my dummy Matrix and "overwrite" it
        if j == 9:
            j=0 #if the counter "j" reaches 9 - the last element - it shall assign j=0 and leave the innermost while loop by "break"
            break 
        j=j+1
    i=i+1

for x in World:
    print(*x)
```

The Problem with the Output should be obvious:
[columns are equal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLBEY.jpg)

I am hopefully u understand what was my Intention here and can help me fix my code. I tried many many Things but i did not fix this. 
I already found a 2-line short solution which i will use in my final Code but i want to run this also on my own because i am convinced this could work also well.

Many Thanks in Advance.
- Wendel

Comment: The `*` operator when used on a list created new references to the list, it does **not** create copies. So, if you change one, you change them all.

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem? How should your output look like?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Klaus and Nico.

I have to think About that but it will help my understanding About python. Thank you.
The Output should look like a completly uncorrelated random Matrix with binary entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the creation of the list.

> NOTE:
>   `[0] * m` returns just a **reference to a list of m zeros, but not a list.**
>   The subsequent repeating of this element creates a list of n items
>   that all reference to the same list (just as well as the operation b =
>   a for lists does not create the new list), so all rows in the
>   resulting list are actually the same string.

```
import random

#World=list(10*[10*[0]]) #this is my dummy matrix
n = 10
World= [0] * n
for i in range(n):
     World[i] = [0] * n

i=0
j=0

while i <= 9:
    while j <= 9:
        World[i][j]=random.randint(0, 1) #here i want to Access a specific element of my dummy Matrix and "overwrite" it
        if j == 9:
            j=0 #if the counter "j" reaches 9 - the last element - it shall assign j=0 and leave the innermost while loop by "break"
            break
        j=j+1
    i=i+1


for x in World:
    print(*x)
```

Suppose that two numbers are given: the number of rows of n and the number of columns m. You must create a list of size n×m, filled with, say, zeros.

The obvious solution appears to be wrong:

```
a = [[0] * m] * n
```

This can be easily seen if you set the value of a[0][0] to 5, and then print the value of a[1][0] — it will also be equal to 5. The reason is, [0] * m returns just a reference to a list of m zeros, but not a list. The subsequent repeating of this element creates a list of n items that all reference to the same list (just as well as the operation b = a for lists does not create the new list), so all rows in the resulting list are actually the same string.

```
n = 3
m = 4
a = [[0] * m] * n
a[0][0] = 5
print(a[1][0])
```

A possible way: you can create a list of n elements (say, of n zeros) and then make each of the elements a link to another one-dimensional list of m elements:

```
n = 3
m = 4
a = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = [0] * m
```

Another (but similar) way: create an empty list and then append a new element to it n times (this element should be a list of length m):

```
n = 3
m = 4
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append([0] * m)
```

But the easiest way is to use generator, creating a list of n elements, each of which is a list of m zeros:

```
n = 3
m = 4
a = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
```

In this case each element is created independently from the others. The list [0] * m is n times consructed as the new one, and no copying of references occurs.

Comment: Very fast and very helpful Information. Many thanks to you!